# How to fix Powerlevel10k Zsh theme in Jupyter lab terminal?

Tags: jupyter, zsh, jupyter-lab

If I run a terminal under Jupyter lab, I obtain the following prompt:

[image]

The various symbols in the prompt are not displayed correctly and replaced with squares.

How to fix Powerlevel10k Zsh theme in Jupyter lab terminal?

Answer (score 1):

In Jupyter lab menu go to:

```
Settings -> Settings Editor -> Terminal
```

and set Font family to `MesloLGS NF`.

You will then see a fixed theme:
[image]

Note:

- If not already done, you have to install [the Meslo Nerd Font patched for Powerlevel10k](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k?tab=readme-ov-file#meslo-nerd-font-patched-for-powerlevel10k)